# Getting response status in Django rest framework renderer class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented my custom Renderer like this:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class CustomJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):

def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):

    //I am hardcoding status and message for now. Which I have to update according to the response.
    data = {'data': data, 'message':'ok', 'status':200 }

    return super(CustomJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

This is working pretty good. Now I want to update `status` using HTTP status code of response and thus providing a custom `message`. So how should I achieve this?

Basically I want the response like this:

`{"status":200, "data":[actual data comes here.], "message":"ok"}`

Comment: What is the type of `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what renderers are made for. You should use a renderer to transform the response into a certain format (json, html, csv, etc) according to the request. By default it will use the `Accept`header, but you could image to pass a querystring parameter to force a different output.

I think what you are trying to do is a custom error exception http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Well on a different note I found out that we can get the `status` information. The `renderer_context` parameter actually contains the following information-

```
{'view': <ViewSet object at 0x7ff3dcc3fac0>, 'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x7ff3dcc37e20>, 'response': <Response status_code=400, "application/json; charset=utf-8">}
```

This means the `renderer_context` parameter is a dictionary and can be exploited in order to modify your response. For example -

```
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if renderer_context is not None:
            print(renderer_context['response'].status_code)
```